# Live activity shows -- instead of seconds in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetliveactivity

Using [Text (timerInterval: context.state.deliveryTimer, countsDown: true),](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAes1.jpg) it shows -- instead of seconds (1:30:--) when the iphone is locked, but its working just fine and countdown every second when the iphone is unlocked (1:30:50)(1:30:49)(1:30:48) and so on

how to solve this issue?

**Here is the screenshot-**

[image: click for the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The "--" is shown because of iPhone 14/15 Pro model's have an always on display. When you lock your device system is setting the refresh rate down to 1Hz to prevent battery drain.